# Issue with Bullet3 contact points on triangle edges

Tags: opengl, bullet-physics

I'm trying to build a character controller using [Bullet3](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3) with OpenGL. I currently have a kinematic body that uses a Ghost body to get all the manifold contacts. The issue I'm facing is in the penetration pass, whereby the list of contact points return a normal from the edge of a triangle. This basically returns an incorrect normal as it is not the triangle normal, which therefore throws off the penetration correction calculation.

[Video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoNJNvqCoLo), which creates a jumping motion on the triangle edges.

Here is the code that gets the list of contact points:

```
void PlayerPhysicsSystem::_penetrationCorrectionPass()
{
    ECS::GhostObjectCapsuleComponent* ghost = _entityManager.getComponent<ECS::GhostObjectCapsuleComponent>(
        _entityManager.getIdByTag("CharacterController")
    );

    assert(ghost);

    btIDebugDraw* debugDrawer = _physics.World().getDebugDrawer();

    btVector3 minAabb, maxAabb;
    ghost->GhostObject->getCollisionShape()->getAabb(ghost->GhostObject->getWorldTransform(), minAabb, maxAabb);
    _physics.World().getBroadphase()->setAabb(ghost->GhostObject->getBroadphaseHandle(), minAabb, maxAabb, _physics.World().getDispatcher());

    bool penetration = false;
    btVector3 penetrationCorrections(0, 0, 0);
    float maxSlope = 32.f;

    _physics.World().getDispatcher()->dispatchAllCollisionPairs(
        ghost->GhostObject->getOverlappingPairCache(),
        _physics.World().getDispatchInfo(),
        _physics.World().getDispatcher()
    );

    btManifoldArray manifoldArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < ghost->GhostObject->getOverlappingPairCache()->getNumOverlappingPairs(); i++) {
        manifoldArray.clear();
        btBroadphasePair* collisionPair = &ghost->GhostObject->getOverlappingPairCache()->getOverlappingPairArray()[i];

        if (collisionPair->m_algorithm) {
            collisionPair->m_algorithm->getAllContactManifolds(manifoldArray);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < manifoldArray.size(); j++) {
            btPersistentManifold* manifold = manifoldArray[j];

            for (int p = 0; p < manifold->getNumContacts(); p++) {
                const btManifoldPoint& pt = manifold->getContactPoint(p);
                btScalar dist = pt.getDistance();

                if (dist < 0.0f) {
                    // slope test
                    glm::vec3 normalGLM(pt.m_normalWorldOnB.x(), pt.m_normalWorldOnB.y(), pt.m_normalWorldOnB.z());
                    float angleDegrees = _calculateNormalAngle(normalGLM);

                    penetration = true;
                    btVector3 correctionDirection = pt.m_normalWorldOnB * dist * btScalar(-0.6);
                    correctionDirection.setY(0);
                    penetrationCorrections += correctionDirection;
                }

                // Draw a sphere at the contact point for visualization
                const btVector3& contactPoint = pt.getPositionWorldOnB();
                const btScalar sphereRadius = 0.1f;
                const btVector3 color(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                debugDrawer->drawSphere(contactPoint, sphereRadius, color);
                
                // Draw the normal at the contact point
                btVector3 pNormal = pt.m_normalWorldOnB.normalized(); // Ensure the normal is normalized
                float r = (pNormal.getX() + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
                float g = (pNormal.getY() + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
                float b = (pNormal.getZ() + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
                
                const btVector3 normalColor(r, g, b);
                const btVector3 normalEnd = contactPoint + pt.m_normalWorldOnB * sphereRadius * 20;
                debugDrawer->drawLine(contactPoint, normalEnd, normalColor);
            }
        }
    }

    // Apply penetration corrections to resolve overlaps
    if (penetration) {
        btTransform correctedTransform = ghost->GhostObject->getWorldTransform();
        btVector3 correctedPosition = correctedTransform.getOrigin() + penetrationCorrections;
        correctedTransform.setOrigin(correctedPosition);

        ghost->GhostObject->setWorldTransform(correctedTransform);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can remove the contact point with the unwanted normal? I have tried creating a custom callback for `gCustomAddedCallback` where I set `btAdjustInternalEdgeContacts` on the triangle mesh, but that doesn't remove or fix those normals.